# Find the matrix associated to T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V=P_2(R)$ and let be $T\colon P_2(R)\to P_2(R)$ such that for every polynomial $f(x)\in P_2(R)$ we have $T(f(x))=f(0)+f(1)(x+x^2).$

I find this $\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}$

but I don't know if am I right

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: I did $T(1)= 1+1(x+x^2) $ and then I write it as linear combination of $1,x,x^2$ and the same for $T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$ is wrong?

Comment: That's right. But you should specify that $A$ is the associated matrix of $T$ **with respect to the ordered basis $(1,x,x^2)$**.